# Managing a queue in JavaScript via callbacks

Tags: javascript, callback

I am working on a page that uses JavaScript to manage a queue. My challenge is my code has nested callbacks. The nested callbacks are confusing me in regards to the scope of my queue. Currently, I have the following:

```
function MyApp() {}
module.exports = MyApp;

MyApp.myQueue = [];
MyApp.queueIsLocked = false;

MyApp.enqueue = function(item, onSuccess, onFailure) {
  if (!MyApp.queueIsLocked) {
    MyApp.queueIsLocked = true;        
    MyApp.myQueue.push(item);
    MyApp.queueIsLocked = false;

    item.send(   
      function() {
        console.log('item: ' + item.id);

        MyApp.queueIsLocked = true;                      
        MyApp.findItemById(item.id,
          function(index) {
            if (index !== -1) {
              MyApp.myQueue.splice(index, 1);
              MyApp.queueIsLocked = false;

              if (onSuccess) {
                onSuccess(item.id);
              }
            }
          }
        );
      },
      function() {
        alert('Unable to send item to the server.');
        if (onFailure) {
          onFailure();
        }
      }
    );
  }
};

MyApp.findItemById = function(id, onComplete) {
  var index = -1;
  if (MyApp.queueIsLocked) {
    setTimeout(function() {
      // Attempt to find the index again.
    }, 100);
  } else {
    MyApp.queueIsLocked = true;
    for (var i=0; i<MyApp.myQueue.length; i++) {
      if (MyApp.myQueue[i].id === id) {
        index = i;
        break;
      }
    }
  }

  if (onComplete) {
    onComplete(index);
  }
};
```

The `send` function behaves differently based on the details of `item`. Sometimes the item will be sent to one server. Sometimes, it will be sent to multiple servers. Either way, I do *not* know when the item will be done being "sent". For that reason, I'm using a callback to manage the queue. When the item is done being "sent", I want to remove it from the queue. I need to use either a timeout or interval to check to see if the queue is locked or not. If its not locked, I want to remove the item from the queue. This check is adding another level of nesting that is confusing me.

My challenge is, I do not believe that the scope of index is working like I expected. I feel like I'm getting a race condition. I'm basing this on the fact that I've written the following Jasmine test:

```
describe('Queue', function() {
  describe('Approach 1', function() {
    it('should do something', function() {
      MyApp.enqueue({id:'QRA', text:'Test A'});
    });
  });

  describe('Approach 2', function() {
    it('should successfully queue and dequeue items', function() {
      MyApp.enqueue({id:'WX1', text:'Test 1'});
      MyApp.enqueue({id:'QV2', text:'Test 2'});
      MyApp.enqueue({id:'ZE3', text:'Test 3'});
    });
  });
});
```

When I execute the test, I see the following in the console window:

```
item: QRA index: 1
item: WX1 index: 2
item: QV2 index: 3
item: ZE3 index: 4
```

Its like the items aren't getting dequeued like I would expect. Am I way off base in my approach of managing a queue? What am I doing wrong?

Thank you for any assistance.

Comment: Why would you ever need to check queueislocked? I don't see anywhere in your code where it is necessary.

Comment: @slebetman Updated the code. My apologies.

Comment: Added code to my answer. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here are some questions you need to think through and answer for yourself about your intent and design:

1. It sounds like the queue represents items you are trying to send to the server. You are adding items to the queue that need to be sent, and removing them from the queue after they have been successfully sent.
2. Do you want your code to send multiple items simultaneously, in parallel? For example, item A is added to the queue, then sent. Before the asynchronous send for A finishes, item B is added to the list. Should the code try to send item B before the send of item A finishes? Based on your code, it sounds like yes.

It seems that you don't really want/need a queue, per se, so much as you want a list to track which items are in the process of being sent. "Queue" implies that objects are being processed in some kind of FIFO order.

If you just want to track items based on id, then you can use an object instead. For example:

```
MyApp.items = {};
MyApp.addItem = function(item){
  MyApp.items[item.id] = item;
  item.send(
    function(){ // success
      MyApp.removeItem(item.id)
    }
  );
}
MyApp.removeItem = function(id){
  delete MyApp.items[id];
  onSuccess(id);
}
```

Also, I don't think you need a lock on the queue. Javascript is single-threaded, so you'll never have a case where two parts of your code are trying to operate on the queue at the same time. When an ajax call finishes asynchronously, your callback code won't actually be executed until any other code currently executing finishes.

Answer (score 3):

The big flaw I'm seeing is that you call `MyApp.queueIsLocked = true` immediately before `MyApp.findItemById`. Because it's locked, the function sets up a timeout (that does nothing), and proceeds to call `onComplete(-1)`.  `-1` is then explicitly ignored by `onComplete`, failing to dequeue, and locking your queue.

You probably meant to retry the find, like this:

```
setTimeout(function() {
  // Attempt to find the index again.
  MyApp.findItemById(id, onComplete);
}, 100);
```

I'm not sure, but I think Jasmine requires explicit instruction to get Timeout functions to fire, using `jasmine.clock().tick`

---

That said, I suggest removing all of the references to `queueIsLocked`, including the above timeout code. Also, if `item.id` is always a unique string, you can use an object instead of an array to store your values.

Here is a suggested iteration, staying as true to the original API as possible:

```js
function MyApp() {}
module.exports = MyApp;

MyApp.myQueue = {};

//Sends the item, calling onSuccess or onFailure when finished
//  item will appear in MyApp.myQueue while waiting for a response from send
MyApp.enqueue = function(item, onSuccess, onFailure) {
  MyApp.myQueue[item.id] = item;

  item.send(function() {
    console.log('item: ' + item.id);
    delete MyApp.myQueue[item.id];
    if (onSuccess) {
      onSuccess(item.id);
    }
  }, function() {
    alert('Unable to send item to the server.');
    if (onFailure) {
      onFailure();
    }
  });
};

//Returns the Item in the queue, or undefined if not found
MyApp.findItemById = function(id, onComplete) {
  if (onComplete) {
    onComplete(id);
  }
  return MyApp.myQueue[id];
};
```

Answer (score 2):

Try to use ECMA 6 Promise or any promise from js framework.Promiseis more suitable for this task. see more at [https://developer.mozilla.org/](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise)

```
function MyApp() {}
module.exports = MyApp;

MyApp.myQueue = [];
MyApp.queueIsLocked = false;

MyApp.enqueue = function(item) {
 return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
      if (!MyApp.queueIsLocked) {
        MyApp.queueIsLocked = true;        
        MyApp.myQueue.push(item);
        MyApp.queueIsLocked = false;

        var onResolve = function() {
            console.log('item: ' + item.id);
            MyApp.queueIsLocked = true;   
            MyApp.findItemById(item.id).then(function(index){
                 if (index !== -1) {
                      MyApp.myQueue.splice(index, 1);
                      MyApp.queueIsLocked = false;
                      resolve(item.id);
                 }
            });     

        };

        item.send(onResolve,reject);
      }
  });
};

MyApp.findItemById = function(id) {
     return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
              var index = -1;
              if (MyApp.queueIsLocked) {
                setTimeout(function() {
                  // Attempt to find the index again.
                }, 100);
              } else {
                MyApp.queueIsLocked = true;
                for (var i=0; i<MyApp.myQueue.length; i++) {
                  if (MyApp.myQueue[i].id === id) {
                    index = i;
                    break;
                  }
                }
                resolve(index);
              }
        });
};
```

Answer (score 0):

move `MyApp.queueIsLocked = false;` to the callback of server send